# jQuery AJAX thrownError=Unknown

Tags: jquery

In the code below:

```
$("document").ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    // error handling
});
```

What is the meaning of `exception`="Unknown"?

I am working with IE9 and jQuery 1.7.1

**Edit:** Some more info-

- statusText = "Unknown"
- responseText = ""
- readyState = 4

I also made tests with FF and IE8, and in both I got exception="timeout" (Which is reasonable in this specific case). My guess that the "Unknown" is merely an IE9 issue.

Comment: What is the `jqXHR.responseText` & `jqXHR.status` values you are getting for the `exception="Unknown"` ??

Comment: @Assaf286294 from the jQuery site comments section:

" If the request failed because JavaScript raised an exception, the
 exception object is passed to the handler as a fourth parameter"

Do you get this error for all AJAX requests or on a particular operation? What is this operation? 

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: @PalashMondal - Edited with more info

Comment: Seems like an IE9 issue. Could you please post the code in jsFiddle?